# Help with JS and functions parameters

Tags: javascript

Does JS support two functions with the same name and different parameters ?

```
function f1(a, b)
{
// a and b are numbers
}

function f1(a, b, c)
{
// a is a string
//b and c are numbers
}
```

Can I use those JS function for IE7, FF, Opera with no problem?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't support what you would call in other languages *method overloading*, but there are multiple workarounds, like using the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Functions/arguments) object, to check with how many arguments a function has been invoked:

```
function f1(a, b, c) {
  if (arguments.length == 2) {
    // f1 called with two arguments
  } else if (arguments.length == 3) {
    // f1 called with three arguments
  }
}
```

Additionally you could type-check your arguments, for Number and String *primitives* is safe to use the `typeof` operator:

```
function f1(a, b, c) {
  if (typeof a == 'number' && typeof b == 'number') {
    // a and b are numbers
  } else if (typeof a == 'string' && typeof b == 'number' &&
             typeof c == 'number') {
    // a is a string, b and c are numbers
  }
}
```

And there are much more sophisticated techniques like the one in the following article, that takes advantage of some JavaScript language features like closures, function application, etc, to mimic *method overloading*:

- [JavaScript method overloading](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-method-overloading/)

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't use function overloading in JS.

But, you can declare just the version with 3 parameters, and then check whether the third argument `=== undefined`, and provide differentiated behaviour on that basis.

Comment: In the event that the caller passes a 3rd argument but its value is *undefined* this test would fail.  Probably better if the function tests **arguments.length** instead.

Comment: If the caller uses `undefined` as the 3rd argument, I'd take that to signal that they'd like the function to be treated as though only two were passed in. I don't really see any other legitimate purpose for passing in `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

No, that will not work, only the 2nd function will be defined on your page.  [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2005/10/02/426345.aspx)'s a source.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript only uses the function that was defined last.

[http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2005/10/02/426345.asp](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2005/10/02/426345.aspx)x

You will need to implement your own logic inside the function to determine which parameters were passed in.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do that ... unless it is OK with you to only have your last definition hold.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use instanceof, example with basic polymorphism.

First create a superclass (ball)

```
// superclass
function Ball() {
    this.play = function() {
        alert("Ball throw");
    };
}
```

and now for some subclasses (types of balls)

```
// subclass
function Basketball() {
    this.play = function() {
        alert("basketball throw");
    };
}
// subclass
function Soccerball() {
    this.play = function() {
        alert("soccer ball kick/throw");
        console.debug("here");
    };
}
// subclass
function Baseball() {
    this.play = function() {
        alert("strike 3 you're out");
        console.debug("here");
    };
}
```

Give them Ball functionality, aka set their superclass via prototype

```
// set subclass functionality
Basketball.prototype = new Ball();
Soccerball.prototype = new Ball();
Baseball.prototype = new Ball();
```

Some polymorphism (create a bunch of balls and play with them all, but play based on type)

```
var bunchOfBalls = [new Baseball(), new Soccerball(), new Basketball()];
for (var i = 0; i < bunchOfBalls.length; i++) {
    bunchOfBalls[i].play();
}
```

Now write a function that takes a ball but only want to to work for specific type of balls (mimic function overloading, more or less)

```
//overloading dependent upon type
function BasketbalOrBaseballOnlyPlay(aBall) {
    if (aBall instanceof Basketball) {
        //special basketball function
    }
    if (aBall instanceof Baseball) {
        //special baseball function
    }

}
```

If aBall is a Basketball so `aBall = new Basketball();` then `aBall instanceof Basketball` would return true for Basketball and false for baseball but true for Ball.

So `aBall instanceof Ball` would return true because a Basketball is a Ball.

[See code live at http://jsfiddle.net/kLCPB/](http://jsfiddle.net/kLCPB/)